# Python line.replace in a text file is adding unwanted blank lines

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, newline

Hi I am Currently trying to write a simple python code that opens a text file, matches a string and then replaces it with a user input. I have managed to get it working (I am positive there is a more efficient way of doing it) except when I print the result to a file it is adding a blank line between each line. As I am doing this procedure twice it then adds two blank lines.

```
import fileinput

text = fileinput.input(files=('default.txt'))
text2 = fileinput.input(files=("temp.txt"))
mp = str(raw_input("enter the first string: "))
pn = str(raw_input("enter the second string"))
fileN = mp + "_autogen_ST.txt"
f = open("temp.txt","w")
fi = open(fileN,"w")
#for line in text:
#   print >>f, (line.replace("*mp*", mp))
for line in text:
    print >> f, (line.replace("*pn*", pn))



for line in text2:
    print >> fi, (line.replace("*mp*", mp))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you not got extra blank lines in the text files you are reading from?

Comment: I think the strings you get from `raw_input`s have a `\n` at the end, try to `.split()` them before replacing

Comment: Hi no the text file it is reading from does not have any extra blank lines, however after printing it, it has added a blank line after every line.  Also have tried to run it after purposefully changing the strings so it finds no match, and it still adds blank lines so assume its not due to the raw inpunt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the lines from the file already have newlines, and `print` adds newlines automatically. The simplest solution is to replace `print` with `f.write`, which is a "raw" output method:

```
for line in text:
    f.write(line.replace("*pn*", pn))

for line in text2:
    fi.write(line.replace("*mp*", mp))
```

Or as one-liners for funsies:

```
f.writelines(line.replace("*pn*", pn) for line in text)
fi.writelines(line.replace("*mp*", mp) for line in text2)
```